# external links within a plotly plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I'm wondering if there is a way to embed external links within a plotly plot (specifically I'm using the plotly package in R, but I don't have to). I want to be able to click on points in a scatter plot and have that take me to an external page with more detailed information about that point. Below is a fake example to demonstrate the idea.

Also, if this is not possible in plotly, but someone knows another library that could do this, I would love to know about that too! Thanks in advance.

THE EXAMPLE:
Imagine we're plotting the distances of each cruise taken by ships owned by two different cruise lines. The code below makes a plot which shows all the voyages and, when you hover over a point, it shows you the name of the ship that took that voyage. *What I want* is to be able to click on a point and have it take me to some web page with, for example, a detailed log of that particular voyage. (This is all a fake example, these logs don't actually exist.) Another sidenote: I'm using `ggplotly` because I'm comfortable with `ggplot2` but if there's a way to do this in `plot_ly` I'm happy to use that.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)

shipNames <- c("Princess", "Voyager", "Paul Simon", "Dangelo", "Virginia", "Meade", "Capt America", "Naw Dawg")

set.seed(1)
cruise <- data.frame(company = sample(c("Carnival", "Norweigen"), 20, replace = T),
                     shipName = sample(shipNames, 20, replace=T),
                     date = sample(seq(from=as.Date('2016-01-01'), to=as.Date('2016-12-31'), by=1), 20),
                     distance = sample(seq(from=300, to=500, by=1), 20)
                     )

g <- ggplot(cruise, aes(x=date, y=distance, colour=company, name = shipName)) + geom_point()
# you have to put the geom_line first or it fucks it up
g <- ggplot(cruise, aes(x=date, y=distance)) + geom_line(aes(colour=company)) + geom_point(aes(colour=company, name = shipName))

ggplotly(g, tooltip = c("x", "name"))
```

Comment: Guess your plot may be in shiny, otherwise, there is no chance to handle click event on the fly. Hence, this link may be helpful https://plot.ly/r/shiny-coupled-events/

Comment: Thank you, although I will be embedding it with the Wordpress plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-plotly/
Sorry, I should have mentioned that.